# How to use projector Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, projector

I have an Acer P5260i projector which has a wireless feature. However the user manual didn't come with the description on how to use this feature. I'm using a laptop. Is there a detailed overview on how I should connect them through wireless?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself 5 minutes after I asked it here. 
I was so lame, because this was so easy.
The projectors settings were messed up and when I resetted them I only needed to

1. select Wi-Fi
2. with laptop connect to it,
3. with browser enter projector's IP
4. download Acer eProjection management and install it.

And that's all. The only thing that something with settings were incorrect so just reset them to factory defaults if something aren't working.

Comment: does the "Acer eProjection management" require a microsoft operating system (like xp, w7 or the like); can it run on Linux?